# New-SPProjectWebInstance error

Tags: powershell

One part of my now rather large install&configure script for SharePoint is giving me much grief.
If i type the command in the shell it works perfect, saying something about "provisioning added to queue"

The fault line is:

```
New-SPProjectWebInstance -Url http://cod**dev:82 -AdminAccount "cod**lab\dkfdsp01_admin" -PrimaryDbserver "codandev" -ReportingDbserver "cod**dev" -PublishedDbname "db_pub" -ArchiveDbname "db_arch" -DraftDbname "db_draft" -ReportingDbname "db_rep" -Wait
```

The error i receive is:
The request channel timed out waiting for an reply after 00:00:59:7888816. Increase the timeoutvalue passed to the call to request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout

Some of the rows prior to this one are:

```
New-SPServiceApplicationPool  -Name $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectapppool -Account $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.adminaccount
New-SPProjectServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectapppool -Name $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectserviceapp
New-SPProjectServiceApplicationProxy -Name ProjectServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectserviceapp
New-SPWebApplication -Name $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectwebappname -Port $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectwebappport -URL $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectwebappurl -ApplicationPool $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectapppool -ApplicationPoolAccount $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.adminaccount -DatabaseName $xmlInput.Configuration.ProjectServer.projectwebcontentdb
```

Comment: I've just tried New-SPProjectWebInstance -Url http://localhost:82 and that works!